# Integromat - save previously attending people and add new to list

Tags: webhooks, make.com

I'm trying to set up a webhook in integromat connected to supersaas so that I can instantly add/edit/delete it in google calendar but I'm failing to find a way to add a new attendee to the already excisting event rather than making another event but only with another attendee.

Since supersaas gives me a `Event: create` per attendee I'm having problems getting the previously attending people, add a new person and edit the google calendar within integromat because I just started using it.

I can successfully find the event from google calender and get the attendee while having the new attendee ready to be added to the collection but I can't find a way with either `Data store` or the `Array aggregator` to combine them.

I was successful combining all attendees to `Data store` but there's no way (that I know off) to get them all out as an array.

The `Array aggregator` seems to only allow 1 entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Data store` and in each route that you have a new email, update your data store like this:

- get current value of your data store
- update the data store and `add` the new email to it

then again get the value of the data store and use it in the google calendar module.

Note that the `attendees` field of google calendar module get and array of objects which means your data store should have a type of `{email:text, name:text}`.